# SoundCloud API's Download endpoint throwing 403

Tags: soundcloud

We've been using soundcloud to provide an audio track that users can play and have been providing a download link pointing at the download endpoint (e.g. `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/0000000000/download?secret_token=s-XXXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`). However, for the last few days these links have been returning `403` errors. (Note: the headers include `X-Cache: Error from cloudfront`.)

Thinking that maybe there was an API change, I tried switching the code to pull the download link directly from the Widget API:

```js
this.soundCloudWidget.getCurrentSound(sound => {
    console.log('got sound', sound);                                                                                          

    if (sound.downloadable && sound.download_url && sound.has_downloads_left) {
        console.log('setting download url:', sound.download_url);
        this.soundcloudDownloadSrc = sound.download_url;
    }
});
```

As of last night, this code returns the same URL (but with a different `secret_token` and `client_id`); however, this URL still gets a `403`. This morning, the `download_url` property is missing.

Is SoundCloud removing download functionality or is this a temporary issue? The API Docs still reference the `download_url`, etc.

Note: even the normal track info URL (e.g. `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/0000000000?secret_token=s-XXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`) returns a `403`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this endpoint to download a track without using the secret token and client id.

https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/{track_id}

Comment: That doesn't appear to work for me. I still get a 403 (e.g. https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/758959528).

Comment: With the track id you're using it doesn't appear to have worked for me as well. I've used this endpoint and with your track id and I was able to download the track. Hope this one works for you.

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/758959528/stream?client_id={client id}

Comment: You could do a GET Track by client id:http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/758959528?client_id={client_id} and you can get the stream_url. Send the request with the client id.